# Is "before getting into analysis proper" correct?

Tags: phrases

In an essay, if we want to review comments already made on a given subject before proceeding to an analysis of said subject, is the following phrase correct?

"Before getting into analysis proper, [we may review etc.]"

Actually three questions in one:

1/ Is "getting into" acceptable, not familiar?

2/ Can "analysis" indeed stand on its own, without an article?

3/ Is "proper" here used properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1/ Is "getting into" acceptable, not familiar?

'Getting into' is informal; here 'commencing' 'starting', or 'becoming involved in' would be more formal.

> 2/ Can "analysis" indeed stand on its own, without an article?

'Analysis' can be used without an article as a non-count noun. You are writing generically about the topic or act of analysis. Try searching for e.g. "analysis is" (with the quotes) for examples of this usage.

*Analysis is considered one ‘composite’ step.*

> analysis noun [ C or U ]
> B2 the act of analysing something
> *Chemical analysis revealed a high content of copper.*

[Analysis (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/analysis)

> 3/ Is "proper" here used properly?

Yes.

> proper adjective (MAIN)   [ **after noun** ] belonging to the main, most
> important, or typical part:
> *It's a suburb of Los Angeles really - I
> wouldn't call it Los Angeles proper.*

[Proper (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proper)

Answer (score -2):

1. Yes, it is acceptable.
2. I honestly don't understand what "without an article" means. But from what I can tell, no. If you want to use your sentence, there's usually context. (If you don't understand, please reply! This is the best answer I can think of)
3. No. The correct sentence is "Before getting into *proper* analysis, [we may review etc.]". Or, you can just not use "proper" and instead use "my" or "your". So, "Before getting into my analysis, ..."

Again, please don't be afraid to ask questions because I'm may have made some mistakes.